# Sql to Hql conversion

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to write a below sql query in hibernate hql. I am using oracle database.

```
SELECT distinct u.user_id,u.user_name
FROM (select abcId, max(upload_date) upload_date, user_id from ABC 
GROUP BY abcId, user_id) abc,users u WHERE abc.user_id=u.user_id
```

I tried my best to write it in hql. Unfortunately I could not succeed. Can anyone throw some light on me to achieve this in hql?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you tried?

Comment: I tried something like this select user,abc,max(abc.uploadDate) from USERS user,ABC abc where abc.userId=user.userId GROUP BY abc.abcId having max(abc.uploadDate)

Comment: Well, this query is radically different. It doesn't even return the same thing. Why don't you translate the SQL literally?

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah I know. I was supposed to say something similar to that I have tried. Not the exact one. In the Amit's answer I have CLEARLY mentioned why am I trying to translate it into hql. I don't have any  history for what I have done to show it to others. I am sure I am going to succeed if that can be converted. Then surely I will post that answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, you have an SQL query, and you want to execute something "similar" in HQL? Either you want it to do exactly the same thing, or you want something different. If we don't know what you want, how could we answer? Tell us what your entities are, how they are related with each other, and tell us what you would like the query to return. Your question, as it is, boild down to "I have some SQL query, and I want to create an HQL query that does something different. How can I do?"

Comment: @JBNizet You are right. Without the detailed information you cannot write the query. I want to write a hql query which returns the same result what that sql query returns. So let me try put more information on this question soon (not now). If you get free time later please try to help me if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think `session.createSQLQuery(String sqlQuery)` may work for you... [see an example here](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql.shtml)

Comment: Thanks Amit. Currently I am using the above mentioned one and app is working fine. Still in nearer future we are planning to change the database to mysql. So I do not want to touch the code that time instead of doing simple database driver change.

Comment: That is the beauty of the Hibernate you dont need to change much. just some properties. It this solved your problem than you can accept it as answer so that this can be useful for others as well. Optionally you can also upvote... and of course that is not compulsory :D ... :)

Comment: Thanks Amit. I have upvoted. Before asking this question itself I was knowing very well that I can use createSql to complete it. My intention is to write it in hql(look at my previous comment). So I am not going to accept this as a answer.